# List.append(int) turns list into nonetype

Tags: python, append

I was trying to add a number to a list(energies) but it kept turning my list(energies) into a nonetype. This is a problem because it says that it can't use the function "count" on a nonetype This is my code

```
import random
Energy = 500
energies = [-2, -1]
Hydrogen = 0
numoep = 0
Eposfind = 0
sethydrogen = 0
times = 0

#Scene setting#
while numoep < 500:
    energies.append(random.randint(1, 100))
    numoep = numoep + 1
    try:
    energies.remove(-2)
    energies.remove(-1)
    except:
    pass

while Eposfind < 100:
    if energies.count(Eposfind) != 1:
    sethydrogen = energies.count(Eposfind)
    Hydrogen = Hydrogen + sethydrogen
    Energy = Energy - 2 * (sethydrogen)
    try:
        energies = energies.remove(Eposfind)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print(Eposfind)
    Eposfind = Eposfind + 1

print("finished")
```

Comment: On which line is the error thrown?

Comment: on this line
if energies.count(Eposfind) != 1:

Answer (score 3):

`list.remove(item)` removes the item and returns `None`. replace the line `energies = energies.remove(Eposfind)` with `energies.remove(Eposfind)`.

Also, it is very inefficient to handle the item not found in the list by `try`-`except`. You should consider using `if Eposfind in energies` instead.

Change

```
try:
    energies = energies.remove(Eposfind)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

to

```
if Eposfind in energies:
    energies.remove(Eposfind)
```

would solve the `None` problem.